# Walkie Talkie on iOS

Tags: ios, networking, bluetooth, wifi, gamekit

I want to create a walkie takie app for ios, and i need a help for start.
Which framework I need to use to achieve p2p connection via Bluetooth/WiFi without LAN.

As i understand Bonjour is not a solution, because iPhone/iPad can not create a Wifi network, am I right ?

what about GameKit framework ?  or maybe the are any other frameworks which will help to connect two devices together.

In the app store I found Voxer Walkie-Talkie app, does anyone know which framework they used ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per this SO question [what-is-the-range-of-bluetooth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658899/what-is-the-range-of-bluetooth-and-is-it-strictly-11) Bluetooth will not make a good choice for a walkie/talkie app as you would have to be in hearing range of the other party in order for it to work.  So you will be stuck with wifi and/or the phone company as a transport mechanism for it to be useful.

And after looking at the [Voxer website](https://support.voxer.com/home), it appears that you have to sign up for an account, and invite people to join you there in order to have a conversation.  So it is hardly p2p.  It is user <-> Server <-> user

You should take a read of Apple's GameKit documentation: [Checklist for Adding Real-time Matchmaking to Your Game](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Matchmaking/Matchmaking.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH9-SW16)  They talk about what network topologies are supported and how to do things like add voice chat to a game - which is sort of what you want to do, except there is no game.

Comment: thanks, and what about using Wifi instead of Bluetooth? does GameKit allow to use Wifi for p2p connection ?

Answer (score 1):

GameKit is the right solution to create a peer-to-peer bluetooth connection. But Bluetooth is not designed for transferring much data over a large distance!

To get an overview about how to use GameKit to create a Bluetooth connection, have a look at the [BluetoothTextMessenger tutorial on mobile.tutsplus.com](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/bluetooth-connectivity-with-gamekit/).

Comment: is it possible to use Wifi instead of Bluetooth ? or GameKit could use only Bluetooth? another question is , is it possible to use SIP protocol with Gamekit ?

Comment: You can use WiFi with GameKit, but WiFi is not a peer to peer network, so you need a WiFi hotspot somewhere. And no, SIP is not possible since you must build on the GameKit protocol.